# Allow Site Access Only Through Specific url

Tags: wordpress

I'm building a microsite where the client wants it to be only accessible when viewed through 1 specific url.

So how can I make the site private without registration? This does not need to be secure, this is simply a client preference.

It's a wordpress site, so if anyone knows any plugins that can do it that'll be great as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a landing page which will set a cookie (or a session if the same domain name) then check the cookie (or a session) within WP site.

Other way you can [check referring URL](http://tltech.com/info/referrer-htaccess/) with .htaccess

In your case:

```
RewriteEngine on

# serve everyone from specific-domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http?://www.specific-domain.com
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# everybody else receives a forbidden
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

ErrorDocument 403 /forbidden.html
```

or if you need from specific page

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !(www.)?specific-domain.com/landing-page.php
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: Yes, I definitely have come across HTTP_REFERER which sounds like it could do what I need but haven't found it actually written out. Are you able to help with this?

Comment: Thank you! this does exactly what I need, but for some reason it's not allowing css to load. The site loads but without any styling and removing your code the site loads normally. Any ideas why?

Comment: Try to add `RewriteRule ^mystyle.css$ - [L]` just under `RewriteEngine on`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do anything, still not loading the css. Any other ideas?

Comment: No clue at that point as CSS should be on the same domain as the main site. You can post that as a new question.

Comment: ok. I noticed that I can't browse the microsite once I'm allowed through. Does your code only work for 1 page?

Comment: It may to do something with `.htaccess` generated by WP. I will check it and update my answer if so.